# Scheduled Bounty

Tags: feature-request

If I do not get a satisfactory answer within the same day, would it be possible to schedule a bounty the same day the question was asked?

Sometimes, I get a single or no answer and when I get busy, I cannot spend time checking for a new answer. I want to come back next time and hopefully find a better answer.

> How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty? A bounty can be
>   started on a question two days after the question was asked

More often than not, I leave the question if I do not get satisfactory answers the same day. That is when I get busy and do not have time to follow up the next day.

*Note: suggestion edited*

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: Thanks ColleenV. Unfortunately two days means must come the next day to start a bounty when sometimes I have only one "free" day for a good answer!  ---------------
How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
A bounty can be started on a question **two days** after the question was asked.

Comment: The time to wait for a good answer is probably at least a few days before you start to worry. Consider that the people that are answering questions might not have time to visit every day too, so you need to give them time to find your question. The best way (IMO) to get a good answer is to have a good, descriptive title, tag your question as best you can (some people watch tags for new questions), respond to comments asking for more information (even if they are a few days old) and then just be patient.

Comment: I agree with you but it is about times when you do not afford to do just that. So it is a feature there at the asker's discretion. I am editing the post for the community to decide anyway.

Comment: Related: [Should the bounty waiting period be reduced to 24 hours?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89678/273494)

Comment: As the nature of feature-requests implies, my downvote on this means that I disagree with your proposal, not that it's of low quality or any other possible reason for downvotes elsewhere. The 2-day wait is pretty effective in avoiding premature and too early bounties. Without it, the bounty system loses some of its meaning.

Comment: Thanks @TIPS I am full aware of the difference between downvoting in the meta and the main ell site. This is very kind of you.

Answer (score 7):

I am going to echo some of what [Shog9 explained in his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133077/273494) to the related question on Meta.

If you want good, timely answers to your questions on Stack Exchange sites, the best way is to write high quality questions and to interact with them often. It can take a week or longer sometimes to refine a question and get a really great answer on ELL, mostly because we're trying to communicate in the language that part of our community is still learning and because sometimes our answers need refining to make sure we're explaining things in an understandable way.

I understand that method requires more effort and time than some folks that just want an answer to their immediate question may want to spend, but that's just the nature of a free site where the answers come from volunteers [and the points don't matter](https://youtu.be/9KAGwNtI26w). Offering a bounty certainly draws attention to your question, but it doesn't necessarily mean you will get a *good* answer sooner than you would have otherwise.

Allowing a bounty to be set earlier than 2 days would also subvert the review process, because it would allow posters to force a question to remain open by paying some of their reputation before the community has had a chance to review it. That incentivizes the wrong behavior by rewarding folks that are answering questions that they should be helping to improve.

If higher reputation users can pay to move their questions immediately to the front of the queue, questions from new users who need the most help learning how to ask on ELL might not get the attention they need to learn how to ask questions that get good responses. It's not good for the community if many new users have a bad experience with their first question.

Comment: Thanks ColleenV for paying attention to this proposal. Point taken under the circumstances. I upvoted for some of the suggestions on the other page.